# npm ERR! code 128 while run npm install on application

Tags: angularjs, node.js

```
 C:\SARANRAJ-K.R\Medrec\meds_6.2.0_update7>npm install


npm WARN deprecated express3-handlebars@0.5.2: THIS PACKAGE HAS BEEN RENAMED TO:
npm WARN deprecated grunt-ngmin@0.0.3: use grunt-ng-annotate instead
npm WARN deprecated phantomjs@2.1.7: Package renamed to phantomjs-prebuilt. Plea
npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@0.12.1: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie
npm WARN deprecated ngmin@0.4.1: use ng-annotate instead
npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@0.9.15: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.2: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie h
npm WARN deprecated deflate-crc32-stream@0.1.2: module has been merged into crc3
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! Command failed: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE checkout 74fd92dc48f95
npm ERR! fatal: reference is not a tree: 74fd92dc48f9575abc701fbd84decad160c5cc6
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\gd14980\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-06-20T05_55_0
```

I got above error while run npm install command

Comment: Update your packages and check if GIT installed then if it's installed check the path is equal to this path 'C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE' if not change it.

Comment: ok thanks for responding

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command.

- sudo npm cache clean -f
- sudo npm install -g n
- sudo n stable
- sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/8.0/bin/node /usr/bin/node

Comment: does 8.0 refer to the version?

Answer (score 0):

I did also faced similar issue while running "npm run bootstrap" and below is the error

> npm ERR! code 128
>   npm ERR! Command failed: git clone --mirror -q git://github.com/rehooks/window-scroll-position.git /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-ab3c3294/.git
>   npm ERR! fatal: could not create leading directories of '/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-ab3c3294/.git'
>   npm ERR!

But below is the solution as it was the issue due to node version.
I previously using below versions due to which it was failing,

- npm --version
  6.10.2
  [Pipeline] sh
- node --version
  v12.9.1

which I changed to,

npm --version
6.10.2
[Pipeline] sh
+ node --version
v12.9.1

and it started working...;)